# (Easy?) calculate change over multiple years as -1, +1 or 0 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, binary, distance

I would like to measure for every job task whether it is (1) new, (2) displaced, (3) has always been present. Whether a task was present in a certain year is binary (1 or 0). The output I need is a simple distance measure and has to be like:

- task has always been present (0)
- task has been removed at any point in time (-1)
- task is newly added (+1)

```
task_id <- c('X001','X002','X003', 'X004')
year2016 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
year2017 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
year2018 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1)
year2019 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
output <- c(-1, -1, 1, 0)

df <- data.frame(task_id, year2016, year2017, year2018, year2019, output)
```

Output column would have to look like this:

```
  task_id year2016 year2017 year2018 year2019 output
1    X001        1        1        1        0     -1
2    X002        1        0        0        0     -1
3    X003        0        0        1        1      1
4    X004        1        1        1        1      0
```

Any suggestions for me to code it? Minor addition: the actual year columns are in standard date format (if that might affect the solution). Thank you so much!!

Comment: Might you ever have a row like, for instance, `1, 0, 1, 0`? If so, how would you want that represented in `output`?

Comment: Hi @AaronMontgomery, that is an extremely unlikely occasion, but if you know how to do it easily, it might have the value of -2.

Comment: How about something like `0, 0, 0, 0`?

Comment: This will not occur. Thank you for helping!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very easy version of this is where we get to ignore cases where rows can look like `1, 0, 1, 0` or `0, 0, 0, 0`. In that case, we can use:

```
df <- data.frame(task_id, year2016, year2017, year2018, year2019)
df$output <- 0  
df[df$year2016 == 0, ]$output <- 1  
df[df$year2019 == 0, ]$output <- -1
```

The logic for the third line is that those not present at the start must have been added at some point; then we check for ones that were present at the beginning but not the end and mark them as having been removed.

---

The logic for the more complicated case is:

- make a new column (`num_switches`) that counts the number of flips in a given row from 0 to 1 or vice versa -- this is what `rle()` does
- automatically mark anything with `num_switches > 2` as having `output = -2`
- for cases where `num_switches <= 2`, mark as above

Full code with an expanded toy dataset below. Note that the `2:5` reference in the `df` subset should match your year columns; the more responsible thing to do here is probably to create an external variable that keeps track of these columns and reference it here (in case you add more years later, for instance).

```
task_id <- c('X001','X002','X003', 'X004', 'X005')
year2016 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
year2017 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
year2018 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
year2019 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
# output <- c(-1, -1, 1, 0)

df <- data.frame(task_id, year2016, year2017, year2018, year2019)
df$output <- 0
df$num_switches <- sapply(apply(df[,2:5], 1, function(x) rle(x)$lengths), length)
df[df$num_switches > 2, ]$output <- -2
df[df$year2016 == 0 & df$num_switches <= 2, ]$output <- 1
df[df$year2019 == 0 & df$num_switches <= 2, ]$output <- -1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron, extremely helpful and great thoughts. Have a great evening..!!

Comment: I was wondering, can with num_switches be identified in what column (year in my case) the change has been made (and output this as a new column)? This would be absolutely stunning to have now I think about it, but I couldn't find so easily

Comment: It definitely can. My kids woke up so I can't come back to this until later - this would probably make sense as a separate question if you want to start one, though.

Comment: Okay, I will post as a separate question! For now.. I get this error, but find it difficult to understand how to solve:
```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, num_switches, value = c(3L, 3L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 19649
```

Any tips, for when your kids have woken up? :) Take your time!!

Extremely appreciated.. thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: Mind posting the exact line you're typing that's throwing this error?

Comment: My best guess is that you didn't replace `df` in the line where you declare `num_switches` with the name of your actual data frame, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for helping so much again Aaron. You were indeed right.. oopssss. Now I have the following error in line `df[df$num_switches > 2, ]$output <- -2`

It is as follows:

`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, output, value = -2): replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

But this makes sense I think because there are no more than 2 switches! So thank you for writing the line but I can simply leave it out I think! Thanks a million again, have a great week ahead!

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution using `case_when` will be:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("year"),names_to = "year","value") %>%
  group_by(task_id) %>%
  mutate(output2 = case_when(last(value) == 0  ~ -1,
                            last(value) == 1 & sum(value == 0) != 0 ~ 1,
                            sum(value == 0) == 0 ~ 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   task_id [4]
  task_id output output2 year2016 year2017 year2018 year2019
  <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 X001        -1      -1        1        1        1        0
2 X002        -1      -1        1        0        0        0
3 X003         1       1        0        0        1        1
4 X004         0       0        1        1        1        1
```

---

**EDIT: With more elaborated example**

Just to complete the answer with the more elaborated example described in the very good answer of @AaronMontgomery, here a solution using `dplyr` and `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("year"),names_to = "year","value") %>%
  group_by(task_id) %>%
  mutate(output2 = case_when(last(value) == 0 & length(unlist(rle(value)$length)) >2 ~ -2,
                             last(value) == 0 & length(unlist(rle(value)$length)) <= 2 ~ -1,
                             last(value) == 1 & sum(value == 0) != 0 ~ 1,
                             sum(value == 0) == 0 ~ 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   task_id [5]
  task_id output2 year2016 year2017 year2018 year2019
  <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 X001         -1        1        1        1        0
2 X002         -1        1        0        0        0
3 X003          1        0        0        1        1
4 X004          0        1        1        1        1
5 X005         -2        1        0        1        0
```